# Json Binding error while fetching information from json string

Tags: c#, json, json.net

```
{
  "conjunctionOp": {
    "conjuctionOp": 1
  },
  "componentList": [
    {
      "valueIdentifier": "LOGIN",
      "valueMask": "LOGIN_FIELD",
      "fieldType": {
        "typeName": "IF_LOGIN"
      },
      "size": 20,
      "name": "LOGIN",
      "displayName": "ID",
      "isEditable": true,
      "isOptional": false,
      "isEscaped": false,
      "helpText": "1427",
    },
  ],
  "defaultHelpText": "9307"
}
```

ABove code is my json response from server.I want to fetch all information from component list.
I am using following method:

```
dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json_additem_response);
foreach (dynamic item in data)
{
    Session["valueIdentifier"] = item.componentList[0].valueIdentifier.ToString();
}
```

Please help me with the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't iterate through your `data` object since it is already a complete JSON object, and not an array.

You can directly access `valueIdentifier` this way:

```
dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json_additem_response);
Session["valueIdentifier"] = data.componentList[0].valueIdentifier.ToString();
```

`foreach` would be suitable if you received an array of objects and had to iterate through them.

Comment: @PrayashBhatt Array is enclosed with `[]` brackets, an object is enclosed with `{}`.

Comment: Thank you very much.It helped.Also I want to send the above information to the web service.how???

Comment: @PrayashBhatt That's kind of another question. However, if you ask it, it will probably be closed as **too broad**. You need to read some literature and external articles on this topic.